How can I build a table with NAMES defined in a workbook?
I'm writing a simple report to document how vba routines manages data collected in a simple workbook.
As part of this, I would like to add a table to list the names defined in the workbook  and referenced in the code (like the table you see selecting formulas and then names in the tool bar)
I used the example provided in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names . The code  follows:
Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names 
Set wks = Worksheets(1) 
For r = 1 To nms.Count 
    wks.Cells(r, 2).Value = nms(r).Name                       ' STATEMENT 1
    wks.Cells(r, 3).Value = nms(r).RefersToRange.Address      ' STATEMENT 2
Next

The result of the execution of STATEMENT 1 is that Cell(1,2) contains the string;  _xlfn.ANCHORARRAY
The execution of STATEMENT 2 resuts in the error message "run-time error 1004" and the detail message says "Errore definito dall'applicazione o dall'oggetto" that I would translate to "error defined by the application or by the object".
The options availble are End / Debug . I used debug and I browsed through the local variables. Item(1) of nms for Name obviously shows the same string I've reported above, while the RefersToRange shows the detail error message I reported previously.
I'm running on windows 10 with Microsoft® Excel® per Microsoft 365 MSO (Versione 2405 Build 16.0.17628.20006) a 32 bit
As Libraries for VB I've selected : Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object libray, OLE automatition, Microsoft Office16.0 Object Library
Thanks for helping.

Given the prefix of the name (_xlfn.), I'm wondering if this name references a lambda function rather than a named range that has a cell address. That might explain the error thrown at Statement 2. A lambda function doesn't have an address.

As noted in this SO post, Excel uses _xlfn and _xlpm for backward compatibility. (Short for "Excel function" and "Excel parameter" respectively?)
_xlfn.ANCHORARRAY specifically references the so-called spilled range operator: #. E.g., suppose in B1 we have:
=SUM(A1#)

With dynamic array formula SEQUENCE in A1:
=SEQUENCE(4)

Now, Excel might automatically add those functions as Names. Depending on the version, it seems, because these particular functions did not trigger this behaviour in my version (Excel 365, v2405 (Build 17628.20110)).
But it does with something like TEXTJOIN:
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,"Hello","World")

When the workbook opens in an earlier version, one will see the formula as follows:
=_xlfn.TEXTJOIN(" ",,"Hello","World")

Meaning: this is a valid Excel function in later versions. (The cell will display #NAME?, not Hello World.)
_xlfn and _xlpm being the only options for these auto-generated Names, you can filter with InStr:
Sub Get_Names()

Dim nm As Name, nms As Names

Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names

For Each nm In nms
    If InStr(1, nm.Name, "_xlfn") <> 1 And InStr(1, nm.Name, "_xlpm") <> 1 Then
        'Do Something
    End If
Next nm
        
End Sub

As mentioned by others (e.g. here and here),: not all Names refer to ranges. So, you will need to decide what to do with the ones that don't.
E.g.,:
Sub Add_Names()

Dim nm As Name, nms As Names
Dim rng As Range
Set nms = ThisWorkbook.Names

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ADDRESS", RefersTo:=Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MEANING_OF_LIFE", RefersTo:="42"
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LAM", RefersTo:="=LAMBDA(X,Y,SUM(X,Y))"

Dim r As Range

For Each nm In nms

    Set rng = Nothing
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = nm.RefersToRange
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Debug.Print ("Name: " & nm.Name & ", Value: " & nm.Value)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print ("Name: " & nm.Name & ", Range: None")
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Name: " & nm.Name & ", Range: " & _
        rng.Address(True, True, xlA1, True))
    End If
    Debug.Print ("------------")
    
Next nm

End Sub

This will print:
Name: _xlfn.LAMBDA, Value: =#NAME?
Name: _xlfn.LAMBDA, Range: None
------------
Name: _xlpm.X, Value: =#NAME?
Name: _xlpm.X, Range: None
------------
Name: _xlpm.Y, Value: =#NAME?
Name: _xlpm.Y, Range: None
------------
Name: ADDRESS, Value: =Sheet1!$A$1
Name: ADDRESS, Range: [Book1]Sheet1!$A$1
------------
Name: LAM, Value: =LAMBDA(X,Y,SUM(X,Y))
Name: LAM, Range: None
------------
Name: MEANING_OF_LIFE, Value: =42
Name: MEANING_OF_LIFE, Range: None
------------

Notice how Excel created _xlfn.LAMBDA, _xlpm.X and _xlpm.Y automatically (because of my LAM).

Not all the names refer to ranges. Use the following code:
Sub MyNames()
    Dim nms As Names, nm As Name
    Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim r As Long
    For Each nm In nms
        If IsObject(nm.RefersToRange) Then
            If Err Then
                Err.Clear
            Else
                r = r + 1
                wks.Cells(r, 2).Value = nm.Name                       ' STATEMENT 1
                wks.Cells(r, 3).Value = nm.RefersToRange.Address      ' STATEMENT 2
            End If
        End If
    Next nm
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


List Names Referring to Ranges

I have created the following names in Sheet2:



Names, Numbers and Chars are ranges while UniNames is a formula.
Chars is of worksheet-scope, while Numbers is hidden.



After running the code, I got the following in the first (left-most) worksheet (the headers were previously added).


Sub ListRangeNames()
    
    Const DST_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1 ' e.g. '"Sheet1"' would be better
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const REMOVE_SHEET_NAME_FROM_NAME As Boolean = True
    Const DEBUG_PRINT_LIST_OF_ALL_NAMES As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If it's the workbook containing this code, use 'ThisWorkbook' instead.
    
    Dim nms As Names: Set nms = wb.Names ' a collection of names always sorted
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(DST_WORKSHEET_ID)
    With dws.Rows(DST_FIRST_ROW)
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
    End With
    
    Dim nm As Name, rg As Range, n As Long, Exclamation As Long
    
    For Each nm In nms
        ' Add a new name to see how the names are sorted and their indices change.
        If DEBUG_PRINT_LIST_OF_ALL_NAMES Then
            Debug.Print nm.Index, nm.Name, nm.RefersTo, nm.Visible
        End If
        If nm.RefersTo <> "=#NAME?" Then ' exclude (hidden) system names
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if name is not a range
                Set rg = nm.RefersToRange
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rg Is Nothing Then ' the range was set; the name is a range
                n = n + 1
                With dws.Rows(n + DST_FIRST_ROW - 1)
                    .Columns("A").Value = n
                    .Columns("C").Value = nm.RefersToRange.Address(0, 0)
                    ' If a name (object) referring to a range is
                    ' of worksheet-scope, its name (property) will be
                    ' something like 'Sheet2!Numbers'.
                    Exclamation = InStr(nm.Name, "!")
                    If Exclamation = 0 Then ' the name is workbook-scoped
                        .Columns("B").Value = nm.Name
                        .Columns("D").Value = "Workbook"
                    Else ' the name is worksheet-scoped
                        .Columns("B").Value = IIf(REMOVE_SHEET_NAME_FROM_NAME, _
                            Right(nm.Name, Len(nm.Name) - Exclamation), _
                            nm.Name)
                        .Columns("D").Value = Left(nm.Name, Exclamation - 1)
                    End If
                End With
                Set rg = Nothing ' reset
            'Else ' the range was not set; the name is not a range; do nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next nm
    
    MsgBox "Names referring to ranges listed.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


In the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) I got the following list of all names:

 1            _xlfn._xlws.SORT            =#NAME?       False
 2            _xlfn.UNIQUE  =#NAME?       False
 3            Sheet2!Chars  =Sheet2!$C$2:$C$11          True
 4            Names         =Sheet2!$A$2:$A$11          True
 5            Numbers       =Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8           False
 6            UniNames      =SORT(UNIQUE(Names))        True


The _xlfn hidden (False) 'system' names' RefersTo property is always equal to =#NAME?. I'm not sure what they are but they could be like a list of recently used functions.
Note how you could use the RefersTo property to retrieve the worksheet names of the ranges and the addresses using simple text functions.


To get the scope, you could also use nm.Parent.Name, which will return either a sheet name or the workbook name.
